# how to update data in mongodb using angular nodejs express

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I want to update the likes' value with 1.

My MongoDB structure is as follows .

```
   {"_id":{"$oid":"5f980a66c4b0d52950bdf907"},
    "course_id":"5002",
    "lecture_id":"451",
    "__v":0,
    "created_at":{"$date":"2020-10-27T11:54:14.842Z"},
    "message":[
    {
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f980a84c4b0d52950bdf90a"},
    "from":{
    "userId":"68819","name":"Developer IIRS",
    "avatar":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/811753.png"
    },
    "content":"ok",
    "likes":0,
    "parent_id":null,
    "created_at":{"$date":"2020-10-27T11:54:44.388Z"}
    }
    ]
    }
```

Here is my code to update value of **likes**

```
    router.post('/:lectureId/:courseId/:id', function(req, res, next) {
      let query = {
        lecture_id: req.params.lectureId,
        course_id: req.params.courseId
    
      };
      let update = { $push: { message: { _id: req.params.id,likes: 1 } } }
    
      var options = {
        new: true
      }
      console.log('Liked', query)
    
      Chat.update(query, update, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          //res.send(err);
          console.log('err',err );
          return err;
        }
        res.json(result);
      })
    });
```

Its basically adding new document. I am stuck here how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

````
  "lecture_id": "451",
  "course_id": "5002"
},
{
  $inc: {
    "message.$[elem].likes": 1
  }
},
{
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem._id": "5f980a84c4b0d52950bdf90a"
    }
  ]
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mongo query.

```
db.collection.update({
  "lecture_id": "451",
  "course_id": "5002",
  "message._id": "5f980a84c4b0d52950bdf91a"
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "message.$.likes": 1
  }
})
```

Try it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YXcH6Nd53fu)

Not an expert in nodejs. Below update statement may work for you.

`let update = { $inc: { "message.$.likes": 1 } }`

Comment: Thanx @wak786 its working as you said but its not what i am looking for. this is adding likes : 1 in every element of message array. but i want to update by adding 1 in likes value with respect to message._id. basically i have like button in my application and when i hit like button with respect to the message it should addon 1 in likes : 1 or like:2 and so on. with respect to the message id. not to all messages .

Comment: woohaaa ! finally its working for me . thanx @wak786 a lot your answer give me adirection. The following works for me. 
`  let update = { $inc: { "message.$[elem].likes"  :1 } }

  var options = {
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem._id": req.params.id
    }
  ]
  }`

Comment: Cool.. Posted an update to answer. Also just saw your answer too. Looks good.

Comment: ya thats also looks good. now i am curious about which solution is better performance wise. bcz i am so new in Mongo so pleas suggest. is my query correct. is it the right way to do the same. ? @wak786

Comment: your query is correct. Only thing different is, in my query update operation already knows which object to update based on filter. In yours it only gets to know that after checking in arrayFilters. Both should work fine in normal workload. I am not not 100% sure but mine can be more performant if you have proper index.

Comment: ok fine. Thanx a lot. ** thums up ** . I will go with your query :-)

Comment: Cool.. Try it out. Accept the answer if it works for you.